# Determining If a Function is a Linear Transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I thought I understood this concept, as it's pretty similar to other ones I've done in linear algebra. Perhaps I'm tired, and just not seeing it right now.

Here's what I know:

> For the vector spaces $V$ and $W$, the function $T: V\to W$  is a linear transformation of $V$ mapping into $W$ when two properties are true (for all vectors $u,v$ and any scalar $c$):
>
> 1. $T(u+v) = T(u) + T(v)$   - Addition in $V$ to addition in $W$
> 2. $T(cu) = cT(u)$ - Scalar multiplication in $V$ to SM in $W$

My book gives an example of proving $T(v_1, v_2) = (v_1 - v_2, v_1+2v_2)$ is a linear transformation. I won't copy the whole thing, but I actually follow it.

However, for practice, I have to determine if this function is a linear transformation from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$...

> $T:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ , $T(x,y) = (x,1)$

I tried doing it, but I honestly wasn't going anywhere or really understanding what I was doing. Can anyone please explain this problem to me? Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is not a linear transformation.

Indeed,

$T(1,0)+T(1,0)=(1,1)+(1,1)=(2,2)$

On the other hand

$T(2,0)=(2,1)\neq (2,2)$

For T to be linear, these would have to be equal.

Comment: Wow, I knew I was overthinking it, I was too busy trying to prove it somehow with components of vectors (like v1,v2 and u1,u2)(no idea tbh), similar to how my book did it. It's usually easier to disprove it. I honestly just needed another view, and this did the trick. Thank you

Comment: No worries. Glad you got it!

Comment: similar question, might require a new thread. Let's say a function is a linear transformation, your inputs don't disprove it and you cant find any that do so. I'm assuming an example of inputs proving it is a LT in their case, is not not adequate to justify it being a LT, as there might exist one that does disprove it ( you just don't know it). Does this mean the correct approach would be to try and abstractly prove it (with representations of vector components v1,v2,etc)? Sorry, If I am not explaining this well.

Comment: I think I see what you're saying. Yes, you have to prove that the transformation satisfies linearity on all vectors. So you'd take arbitrary v1 and v2, and you would check that T(v1+v2)=T(v1)+T(v2). You'd also check that for any scalar c, and any vector v T(cv)=cT(v).

Answer (score 16):

One consequence of the definition of a linear transformation is that every linear transformation must satisfy
$$ T(0_V)=0_W $$
where $0_V$ and $0_W$ are the zero vectors in $V$ and $W$, respectively. Therefore any function for which $T(0_V)\neq 0_W$ cannot be a linear transformation.

In your second example,
$$ T\Big(\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\end{bmatrix}\Big)=\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\end{bmatrix}\neq\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\end{bmatrix}$$
so this tells you right away that $T$ isn't linear.

Comment: Thanks! I see how both properties fail now. I'm not quiet sure where I was going on my own paper work, completely different direction.

Answer (score 0):

Let $$v = (v_1,v_2) $$and $$w = (w_1, w_2)$$
From the definition of a linear transformation : $$T(v+w) = T(v) + T(w)$$

so, $$T(v) = [v_1,1]$$  and $$T(w) = [w_1,1]
T(v) + T(w) = [v_1+w_1, 2]$$

$$T(v+w)... v+w = (v_1+w_1,v_2+w_2)$$

$$T(v_1+w_1, v_2+w_2) = [v_1+w_1, 1] $$

$$T(v+w) = [v_1+w_1, 1]$$

so, $$T(v+w) \neq T(v) + T(w)$$
therefore, T is not a linear transformation.

Comment: Please read and practice from [The mathjax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference?r=SearchResults&s=9|37.5212)